# welcome page is not showing in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

hi m trying to work with folder structures in node.js but nothing is working, firstlr I just wants to get welcome page but it says: "Cannot GET /"

homeController:

```
  router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('welcome'));
```

app.js:

```
  // Controllers
    const homeController = require('./controllers/homeController');
    const userController = require('./controllers/userController');

  // Routes
    app.get('/crud/create', (req, res) => res.render('crud/create'))


  app.use('/home', homeController);
  app.use('/user', userController);
```

here is complete structure view:
 https://ibb.co/44xfcqj

Comment: may be home controller cannot listen to '/' urls as it start with "/home'. Try putting a simple '/' url at the app.js and see if this works.

Comment: it not works...

Comment: not works or now works ? :). If not then maybe you can share more of your code.

Comment: your `welcome` page would be displayed under the `/home` route, something along the lines of `localhost:3000/home`

Comment: yes its showing on localhost:3000/home but I wants to show it at localhost:3000

Comment: @theusguy  its showing on localhost:3000/home but I wants to show it at localhost:3000

Comment: @pro as pointed by @theusguy u'll need to put something like `app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('welcome'));` in **app.js**. Since you are rendering welcome page on a route handler that is bound to `/home`

Comment: now its working fine